# How to use QPainterPath?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qpainterpath

I'm using pyqt to try to create an application which display images and curves.

To draw bezier curves, I found [the QPainterPath class](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html) and specifically  [QpainterPath.cubicTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainterpath.html#cubicTo). 
However, I don't understand how this class must be used. In which widget should I draw my curves?

I see there are [Qpainter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpainter.html) and [QGraphicsView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html)/[QGraphicsScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html), but I don't know how to use my `QPainterPath` with them.

Do you have any example of the use of `QPainterPath` with pyqt/pyside? (for example, a simple window which displays a cubic bezier curve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QPainter is a pretty low-level class. For simple applications you can ignore it. Add a QGraphicsView widget and do something like this:

```
# Prepare the QGraphicsView widget
scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene(graphicsView)
graphicsView.setScene(scene)
graphicsView.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)

# Draw a line
path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
path.moveTo(0, 0)
path.cubicTo(100, -20, 40, 90, 20, 20)
scene.addPath(path)
```

Comment: I think that a line is missing at the beginning : `graphicsView = QtGui.QGraphicsView()`. With this, it works.

Answer (score 5):

You can draw on a custom widget. The drawing is done within the `paintEvent()` method :

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):      

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Draw Bezier')
    self.show()

def paintEvent(self, event):


    startPoint = QtCore.QPointF(0, 0)
    controlPoint1 = QtCore.QPointF(100, 50)
    controlPoint2 = QtCore.QPointF(200, 100)
    endPoint = QtCore.QPointF(300, 300)

    cubicPath = QtGui.QPainterPath(startPoint)
    cubicPath.cubicTo(controlPoint1, controlPoint2, endPoint)


    painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
    painter.begin(self)
    painter.drawPath(cubicPath);
    painter.end()
```

This adds a cubic Bezier curve between `startPoint` and `endPoint` using the control points specified by `controlPoint1`, and `controlPoint2`.

Comment: What is the difference between Qpainter and QGraphicsScene used by pdw ?

Comment: The `QPainter` class performs low-level painting on widgets and other paint devices. You can use it for painting in `QWidget` or in a `QGraphicsItem`. `QGraphicsItem` could be added on scene and displayed on a view. The `addPath` in the mentioned solution creates and adds a path item to the scene.